# Python Pandas: Copy rows in a datafrme to a new dataframe only if filter condition matches on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and am using Pandas to deal with some data formatting. Below is the sample data and the code I am trying. I am sure what I am doing is not the right approach as its not giving the desired output.

```
if 'US' in df1['Loc'].values:
    df2 = df1

df1:
ID  Name    Loc Age Role
1   Alex    US  25  Devloper
2   Bob     US  34  Manager
3   Chris   IN  21  Tester
4   Dan     JP  41  Architect
5   Eva     US  53  Manager
6   Fred    JP  32  Devloper
.   .       .   .   .
.   .       .   .   .
.   .       .   .   .
999 Greg    DN  38  Devloper


df2 (desired output only rows with US location ):
ID  Name    Loc Age Role
1   Alex    US  25  Devloper
2   Bob     US  34  Manager
5   Eva     US  53  Manager
.   .       .   .   .
.   .       .   .   .
.   .       .   .   .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is a subset of `df1` that contains rows where a condition is met. You wouldn't look to use a for loop for that in pandas but rather would do some [conditional subsetting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe) i.e.

```python
df2 = df1[df1.Loc == 'US'].copy()
```

[`.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) is used here to copy the dataframe rather than create a reference to it as I assume you might want to perform some additional operations on the subset.